# Android: Forcing a WebView to a certain height (or triggering scrolling for a div)

Tags: android, webview, android-widget

I am building an app which contains an input form and a WebView.
The project is available at http://code.google.com/p/android-sap-note-viewer/

The WebView will render a website based on the input and this page has a DIV with the main contents (could be hundreds of lines). I have no control of the contents on the website.

Android WebKit doesn't seem to do any scrolling in a DIV, ref http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=147. Therefore, only parts of the DIV is shown to the user, with no method of retrieving the rest of the text. **My challenge is to find a way that all the text of the DIV is shown**.

My view is defined as the following:

```
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/lblNote" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtNote" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numeric="decimal"
            android:maxLength="10"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/bView" 
          android:text="@string/bView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             />
    </LinearLayout>    

    <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="false"
    android:minHeight="4096px"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I've tried to hardcode the WebView to a large height in order to make sure the DIV is stretched out and shows all the text, and also force the LinearLayout to do the scrolling.

However, the WebView is always adapting to the screen size (which would be good in most cases, but not this).

**Any ideas on how to solve this problem?**

(only solution I see now is to fetch the HTML myself, remove the DIV and send it to the WebView)

Comment: Can you supply (or mock up) some HTML that demonstrates your `<div>` scrolling problem?

Comment: An example HTML is available from dropbox http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4379928/note_example.html 
The main div starts with <div class="urTxtStd" id="NoteContent">

Comment: ended up with rewriting the style of a div on the fly before passing it to the WebView

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting to use weights for this. I am a little confused by your xml code because you have an extra LinearLayout tag, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
           android: orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/lblNote" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtNote" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numeric="decimal"
            android:maxLength="10"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/bView" 
          android:text="@string/bView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             />
    </LinearLayout>    

    <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the Webview will fill the rest of the screen that the inner LinearLayout does not use, since only the webview has a weight attribute.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can put a ScrollView outside the LinearLayout

Comment: will try and come back with the results